# How to bind a tabcontrol to several User Controls

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I would like to bind a TabControl to User Controls in order to have each User Control in a TabItem.

Is this possible, knowing the TabControl is itself in a UserControl ?

Here's the Dependency Property in the UserControl :

```
public IList<UserControl> ListUserControls
    {
        get { return (IList<UserControl>)GetValue(ListUserControlsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListUserControlsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ListUserControls.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListUserControlsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ListUserControls", typeof(IList<UserControl>), typeof(NavigationPane), new PropertyMetadata(new List<UserControl>()));
```

In the MainWindow where is the UserControl :

```
<pyRGC:NavigationPane.ListUserControls>
    <pyRGCTest:UC_1 />
</pyRGC:NavigationPane.ListUserControls>
```

When I code this, it displays me : "The following type was expected : "IList'1"".
I don't find how to use a IList in XAML.

How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed question?  What have you attempted, and/or what is not working correctly?

Comment: In a User Control, I've got a TabControl that has to displays User Controls. I tried to bind the ItemsSource property of the TabControl to a Dependency Property of the User Control that owns it. But I don't really know which type of Dependency Property I have to use for a list of UserControl. I don't even know if it is the good approach.

Comment: If you are using MVVM, then you could bind a collection of viewmodels to ItemsSource and then provide some DataTemplates for each type of viewmodel.

Comment: you beat me to it, @sthotakura

Comment: I'm not using MVVM for this project.

Comment: @CurtisWheller So, if I understand you correctly, you want to display a fixed number of tabs in a tabcontrol and each with a different content (user control)?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to display a fixed number of tabs and you are not using `MVVM`, you will have to provide `TabControl` items in `XAML` rather than via `Binding`.

Sample code is as below:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Items>
        <TabItem Header="Tab One">
            <local:UserControl1 />
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Tab Two">
            <local:UserControl2 />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl.Items>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Indeed it's a good idea to add the usercontrol as tabitem. But how can I bind the different tab item to the tabcontrol ? Actually, it's another person who will create the list of usercontrol, and he uses my usercontrol, that contains the tabcontrol, as a library. So he can't modify the code of the tabcontrol.

Comment: I misspoke, the number of tabs is well fixed but by another person. So in my usercontrol I can't put a fixed number of tabs, it must be as a list.

Comment: @CurtisWheller In that case have you tried binding to `IList<UserControl>`?

Comment: When I use a IList<UserControl> Visual Studio says that the followed type was expected : "IList'1". Here's the code : <pyRGC:NavigationPane.ListUserControls>
  <pyRGCTest:UserControl_Test1 />
</pyRGC:NavigationPane.ListUserControls>

Comment: Excuse me for the layout of my answer but I don't find how to display in a good manner the code.

Comment: @CurtisWheller Perhaps you could edit your question to include the code for your dependency property definition and how you're trying to set it? Using `IList<UserControl>` should work providing your DP is setup correctly